# Wordpress still trying to connect to old database

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, ubuntu

I am Running wordpress on Ubuntu 18.04 with apache2 and PHP 7.2.24. I deleted the wordpress files and dropped the database to copy another wordpress site. I copied the other wordpress (Files and database) into a new database (new name, new user, new password), Then changed the wp-config.php file values to the (new name, new user, new password). Now when I try to open the site it still trying to connect to old databases as if I didn't change the wp-config.php file, I get this error

> Can’t select database

> We were able to connect to the database server (which means your username and password is okay) but >not able to select the v3GMwXpnRQjq database.
> Are you sure it exists?
> Does the user zJ6epncZUYcQ have permission to use the v3GMwXpnRQjq database?
> On some systems the name of your database is prefixed with your username, so it would be like >username_v3GMwXpnRQjq. Could that be the problem?

Comment: what's in your `wp-config.php` file?

Comment: Did you grant that user permissions on that database?

Comment: permission was granted to the user yes, this is the command used in mysql
>CREATE DATABASE KeH5heg53U9zBE; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON KeH5heg53U9zBE.* TO 'DoQwpZV1Vtlq8w'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'bQvil5Sq1RXrPI'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Comment: wp-config.php values

define('DB_NAME', 'KeH5heg53U9zBE');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'DoQwpZV1Vtlq8w');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'bQvil5Sq1RXrPI');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

Comment: Can you confirm MySQL or MariaDB? The former doesn't support `GRANT` with a password as of a specific version (8, I think), so maybe there was an error if you don't use that one?

Comment: it is a mariadb
Server version: 10.1.48-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu 18.04